# Trying to not convert spaces with 'ord()' in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write code that will convert a text file into numbers, and then add an offset factor to it to change the lettering when later converted into ASCII - everything works swell until I have to not convert the spaces into a number using 'ord(x)'

Here is the code:

```
def TextFileEncyption(OFkey, Str):
    '''This will convert the text file that the user inputted earlier, using the offset factor to do so'''
    Message = ""
    print("The program is now going to encrypt your chosen text file...")
    for x in Str:
        if x == 32:
            pass
        else:
            number = ord(x)
        newNumber = number+OFkey
        if newNumber > 126:
            newNumber = newNumber - 94
        ASCIIletter = chr(newNumber)
        Message += ASCIIletter
    print(Message)
```

I've tried the code as `'If x == space'` (where space is a variable as `space = " "`), and code like `'If x == " "'`.

How can I best solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you give examples of expected input & output, and how the output of your code differs from what's expected?

Comment: There is no problem with ``if x == ' '``. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @bgporter well the output changes each time as an 8 character key is generated each time the code runs, allowing the code to be encrypted different each time - however, I'm expecting spaces between the parts of the file that have had 'ord(x)' applied to them, but spaces are converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that you want to preserve the spaces as is, but encrypt all the other characters by rotating them the offset amount?

Something like:

```
def TextFileEncyption(offset, txt):
    '''This will convert the text file that the user inputted earlier, 
       using the offset factor to do so'''
    Message = ""
    print("The program is now going to encrypt your chosen text file...")
    # go through each character in the input text
    for char in txt:
        number = ord(char)
        # ...and only modify characters that are *not* a space character
        if number != 32:
            number = number + offset
            if number > 126:
                number -= 94
        # ...then convert the value back into a character
        ASCIIletter = chr(number)
        # and append it to the message variable for output.
        Message += ASCIIletter
    print(Message)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    inText = "This is a test of the function."
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        inText = sys.argv[1]
    TextFileEncyption(10, inText)
```

gives output like:

```
bgporter@Ornette ~/temp:python soEncrypt.py "A test of the encryption function."
The program is now going to encrypt your chosen text file...
K ~o}~ yp ~ro oxm|%z~syx p!xm~syx8
```

Comment: I will test this when I am back in school but the understand is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
if x == ' ':
```

but there is a problem in the algorithm anyway. What if you `Str` parameter starts with a space? Your `number` variable is undefined during the first pass then.

Answer (score 0):

As dlask said you can use if x == ' '. Which you have already tried. I belive the issue that you have is not actually in that area. As it stands when you have a space you skip the first if / else statement.

```
    newNumber = number+OFkey
    if newNumber > 126:
        newNumber = newNumber - 94
    ASCIIletter = chr(newNumber)
    Message += ASCIIletter
```

However, 'number' is still set from the previous letter, which ultimately causes a repititon of the character before the space. The code below sets the encrypted letter to be a space when the input is a space. Is that what you are after?

```
for x in Str:
    if x == ' ':
        ASCIIletter = ' '
        pass
    else:
        number = ord(x)
        newNumber = number+OFkey
        if newNumber > 126:
            newNumber = newNumber - 94
        ASCIIletter = chr(newNumber)
    Message += ASCIIletter
print(Message)
```